# sql join using column names and derivations from column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Table A has column [9] (of number type)

Table B has columns [10],[11],[12]... (there are many more columns but I need 2 at a time)  (all of number type)

In table RESULT I need to combine A.[month] + (B.[month+1] * B.[month+2])

Example:

```
Table A
Person/ 9 
Joe    50

Table B
Person/ 10/ 11/ 12/ 13 ...
Mary   3   4    5   44
Joe    6   5    1   11
```

Result:

```
Person Calc
Joe     50 + (6*5)=50+30=80
```

**For each person found in both tables, calculation is: 
value on column x from table A + (value on column x+1 from table B * value on column x+2 on table B)**

How is it best to do this?

Considering that from what I know in Sql a column name should be fixed, while I need to reference columns by derived names (month+1, month+2... etc)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What determines whether you need columns 10&11 from B, vs. 11&12, 12&13, etc.?

Comment: It would be best to redesign you data and tables to be more relational.  Then this would be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql to build a statement that you then execute using `EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL` like this:

```
DECLARE @month INT
SET @month = 9

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT a.person, a.[' + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR)+'] + (b.[' + CAST(@month+1 AS VARCHAR) +'] * b.[' + CAST(@month+2 AS VARCHAR) + ']) AS Calc FROM TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.person = b.person'

--PRINT @sql                  -- uncomment this line to see the statement that will be executed
--EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql     -- uncomment this to execute the statement
```

The code above should be easy enough to turn into a stored procedure that takes `month`as a variable. Also the casts and so can most likely be improved; this is the quick and dirty version...

As pointed out in the comments a better solution, if possible, might be to alter the schema of the database instead.